# $.ajax call not recognized by TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: modal.href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: modal.$form.serializeArray()
    })
        .done(onSubmitDone)
        .fail(onSubmitFail);
```

TypeScript points to the $.ajax and gives a message saying:

Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

However from what I can see my $.ajax is correct and I am correctly referencing the jQuery definitions. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to jquery.d.ts:

```
ajax(url: string, settings: JQueryAjaxSettings);
```

This is the signature of ajax function. You should move the url out of the settings object and pass in as a parameter instead for typescript to accept. Or edit the jquery.d.ts definitions to accept settings only function call.

Comment: This is no longer the case. The signature `ajax(settings: JQueryAjaxSettings);` exists in the current version of jquery.d.ts, so his code should work now as-is.

Answer (score 3):

While the initial jQuery definitions do not contain the overload without the Url, they have been updated and you can take the latest version from CodePlex:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

There is also a mirror of the latest updated jQuery definitions at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped